# Git managing separate directories under the same repo

Tags: git

I have two directories on my home folder assignments and assign-workspace. I want to manage them under the same repository, but I don't want the home directory to be the root. At the same time I don't want the contents to be duplicated across both assignments and assign-workspace.
Something like

```
jagat ~/assignments $ git init && git remote add origin <git_url> && git add -A .
jagat ~/assignments $ git commit -m "Stuff from assignments" && git push origin master
jagat ~/assignments $ cd ../assign-workspace/
jagat ~/assign-workspace $ git init && git remote add origin <git_url> && git add -A .
jagat ~/assign-workspace $ git commit -m "Stuff from assign-workspace" && git push origin master
```

In the end, all the directories under assignments and assign-workspace should be managed under the same repository.
I know it's a better practice to have both of them under a different directory "assignments_all", which I've already done.

Now, I'm just curious if it can be done in the first place.

Comment: you can use apache for that... place folders into /var/www. the folders would be accessible using host/app1 and host/app2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.  How would git know the difference between ~/assignments/README and ~/assign-workspace/README?

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be to create a new directory, place both directories which you wish to be managed by git under that directory, and create the repository there.

Then, create symlinks to those directories from your home directory.

Comment: Thanks Sreservoir for the answer. But I've already done that, as I've mentioned in the post. I'm wondering if it can be done without moving the directories around.

Comment: Not symlinks. There is Git toll called submodule.

Comment: I meant, create the symlinks in the home directory, so that they can for most purposes still be referred to with the previous paths.